# Display the beginning part of a page content on every page - wordpress

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress

I have built a Twentyeleven template site in wordpress, I only use pages in CMS (no posts). I have a page called "Classes", its page content will be updated regularly.

I'd like to add a square on the right hand corner of every page which displays the beginning part of the 'Classes' page, and a 'more' link underneath can lead people to the 'Classes' page.

At the moment, I just added a html div in the content-page.php as I am learning. Is there a plugin can achieve what I am aiming? Or can you please give me some directions on how to code this (some suggested code or learning links would be helpful)?

Thank you.

Comment: How about using a plugin? Try googling `wordpress page excerpt widget`.

Comment: Hi Afekenholm, thanks for your reply. This looks like just what I need. How do I add this widget to every page (not posts)? I can see it on my test 'post' page through sidebar. However the sidebar doesn't show on pages. I am learning so any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: How about another plugin? :) [Dynamic Sidebars](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamics-sidebars/)

Comment: Thank you afekenholm, it is working with those plugins, wordpress is very easy when you know where to look. Thank you. I'll also try to learn other options below. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do it in PHP you can try something like this

```
<?php         
    $page_id = 11; //set page ID
    $page_data = get_page($page_id);
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink($page_id);
    echo '<a href="'. $permalink .'">'. $title . '</a>';
    echo '<p>' . the_excerpt() . '<a href="'. $permalink . '">Read more</a></p>';
?>
```

---

If you need the page ID for this script you can use this

```
<?php
     $pages = get_pages();
     foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
         echo 'ID: '. $page->ID . ' title: ' . $page->post_title.'<br>';
     }
?>
```

---

If you are trying to do it based on a widget you need to ensure these steps.

Inside the Twenty Twelve theme you have the section called **Main Sidebar** in the **Widgets** section.  From this area you would add your widget that you want and ensure that all the **pages** you want the widget to be in is set to the "**default theme**" and not "Full-width Page Template, No Sidebar".

Also I do not know if you have made any changes to your code but if you have, you need to ensure that your wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/index.php still has this prior to the footer section.

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

---

If you want to widen your widget area you can tamper with the CSS that controls the width but be warned that this could affect the stability of the items inside your container.

wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css

Line 1446 - 1449

Edit the Width of

```
.widget-area {
    float: right;
    width: 26.041666667%;
}
```

You would also need to edit the Main site-content to have the proper proportioned percentage if the prior value is edited.

Line 1437 - 1440

```
.site-content {
    float: left;
    width: 65.104166667%;
}
```

---

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your detailed explaination, yes I tried this method, the sidebar has showed in a very narrow way, I presume I just need to change the css somehow? Also I'm trying to learn how to do it in php like Sunyatasattva suggested below, unfortunately it's not working. Would you be able to share any light on php if i don't use widget? Thanks Robert.

Comment: The widget is supposed to maintain within the container space.  Are you trying to accomplish something that is outside the container or something that is side by side with the main content with equal width?  I think you may want to revise your question as it is unclear what you exactly want at this moment.

Comment: I went ahead and added the changes to my answer.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

#### You don't have to use a plugin

The thing you are trying to achieve is quite easily done by editing your template files, depending on your needs. I will suggest the simplest solution, but perhaps you may transform this snippet into a widget for a more dynamic/maintainable usage.

1. Edit the `page.php` template file in order to make something appear in every page of your Wordpress installation.
2. Set up the desired layout for your box (perhaps `<div>` with some `float: right`).
3. Get the page you desire and store it into a php variable,  like so: `<?php $page = get_page( $page_id ); ?>`
4. Get the position of the `<!--more-->` tag, using `stripos`.
5. Get only the part before the `<!--more-->` tag, using `substr`.
6. Apply `the_content` filters and then `echo`.

Your code will look a bit like this:

```
<div class="right-info">
    <?php
    $page = get_page(id);
    $more_tag = stripos( $page->post_content, '<!--more-->' );
    $excerpt = substr( $page->post_content, 0, $more_tag ); 
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $excerpt);
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sunyatasattya, thanks for your reply. I'm very keen to learn how to do it in php, I have a div in place already. I tried your php code but it shows blank after I put $page_id=11; in as well. Would you be able to explain your code more? Or do you know any place I can learn it? Thank you.

Comment: Where did you put `$page_id=11`? In the second line of code it is sufficient for you to set: `$page = get_page(11)`.